# C# - File Binding Issue

Tags: .net, io, merge, bind, exe

I'm currently making a file binder in C#, and I have encountered a problem.

When the user inputs 2 files, their assembly code is stored into 2 byte arrays (using the ReadAllBytes function).

The problem is, I don't know how to merge these 2 arrays into one assembly (EXE file).

Can I, programmatically, merge 2 byte arrays into one EXE file, that'll run both byte arrays (files' assembly code) when opened?

Edit - Example code:

```
byte[] file1 = File.ReadAllBytes(path1);
byte[] file2 = File.ReadAllBytes(path2);
```

Now, how do I compile an EXE file that runs both these files?  (each array contains full file data)

I've tried to WriteAllBytes to a single file from 2 arrays, but this didn't work.

So, in other words, how do I compile a file (programatically in C#) that opens 2 other files, that their bytes are already included in that file?

Comment: Do they have any fixed jump instructions or references? Is the first array an open-ended assembly? How could you debug that open-ended assembly? Maybe you can write a C# that runs those two binares consecutively?

Comment: Hello, I've updated the post so it could be better understood. Please read it again.

Comment: Merge or concatenate?

Comment: Merge, and I mean one exe file that'll include both 2 byte arrays, and use them to create and run the files from the byte arrays. The C# compiler should create an assembly file, that when executed, will launch both files from the 2 bytes array in its code.

Comment: Smells like antivirus-evading action :) array1 is not virus trace, array2 is not virus trace, binder is not a virus too. But the merging may become virus :P

Comment: Not to evade any antivirus, but even if the binded file can be flagged as a virus, how can I bind these files into one executable that launches both files?

Comment: Which compiler/interpreter you use?

Comment: Microsoft C# Express 2010.

Comment: Compile for multithreaded (not dll) to include everything in that exe file. Then you may write those in a single file programmatically without needing external files.

Comment: Compiling for multithreaded? I tried writing the two byte arrays one after the other to an EXE file, and only the first file I wrote opens up. So how can I code such a thing? I didn't really understand how to do this multithreaded...